# Returning an anonymous function/lambda that is a curried function

Tags: scala

Just trying to get a handle on some FP patterns.

Can someone show and explain a function that returns an anonymous method/lambda which is also a curried function?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```scala
val foo: Int => Int => Int = x => y => x + y
```

Function `foo` has a signature of `Int => Int => Int` which means that calling it for some argument (what is also called partial application), it returns another function of signature `Int => Int`:

```scala
val bar: Int => Int = foo(1)
```

That you can call following way:

```scala
val result = bar(2)
result == 3
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone show and explain a function that returns an anonymous method/lambda which is also a curried function?

One of the easy ways to see it is to create a currried sum method:

```
def sum(x: Int): Int => Int = y => x + y
```

And call it:

```
val curried: Int => Int = sum(1)
println(curried(2)) // will yield 3
```

If you want to transform the method to a function, you can use eta expansion:

```
val sumFunc: Int => Int => Int = sum _
println(sumFunc(1)(2))
```

Comment: what is eta mean?

Comment: Not sure what ETA stands for, but that's what it's called. Google eta expansion, plenty of good blog posts on the subject.

Comment: @coolbreeze η-expansion is a Scala's made up term for converting a method to a function. Originally it was defined in lambda calculus (some details here: https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion) along with α, β and, not surprisingly,  λ.